# Displaying an Image Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Fitness App. My app will have different exercises like *Push Ups* and *Sit Ups*. Every exercise need to have an image to show to the user.
I have been thinking a while on what is a good way to solve this problem. But I don't think my solution below is good. Have you worked with images on Android for displaying images? Give me your solution on how you did it.

An exercise have a name but also images. The purpose is to display a specific Exercise with the images and exercise name.

My Exercise class looks like this right now:
I have thought of having the path to the image saved which I can have access when I need to show the image. I am uploading the images on the assets folder.

```
public class Exercise {
     private String exerciseName;
     private String exerciseSmallImagePath;
     private String exerciseLargeImagePath;

public Exercise(String exerciseName, String exerciseSmallImagePath, String exerciseLargeImagePath){
    this.exerciseName = exerciseName;
    this.exerciseSmallImagePath = exerciseSmallImagePath;
    this.exerciseLargeImagePath = exerciseLargeImagePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an activity and change an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)'s image based on the name of the excersice.

I suggest just adding the images to the resources folder so you can access them the way you should.

Comment: so are u facing any issue with your current implementation ?

Comment: `Have you worked with images on Android for displaying images?` this made my day :D         //What issues are you having with images?

Comment: Is it a good to save the exercise name and image path? Or should I name the image so I know from the image name which exercise it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saving the path to the image-source is definitly a good approach. Have a look at `ImageViews` in order to display your image. There are two approaches to implement such an ImageView:

1: define it in your `XML` and set the image-source afterwards in your oncreate-method:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="Some description" />
```

2: define your ImageView programmatically in your `Activity`:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(vp);        
imageView.setImageResource(fetch your ID here);        
someLinearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are familiar with how to create simple application in Android? If not, then you should get started with samples and reading up on [Android developers guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

[This article](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/imageview/android-imageview-example/) can give you good start in how to work with Images.

As for how you should accomplish this, I can only suggest one approach, the rest is upto your imagination. 
Start with creating a [fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) that has an image and a text below (or above if you like) it. You can then put this fragment where you want with new image and text.
Here is a rough idea

```
<LinearLayout (vertical orientation>
 <Image ... />
 <Text ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Once the layout is in place you can set the image source at runtime.

A good way to display this information is to have steps which user can navigate using swiping ([view pager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)).

Every page can have the above mentioned fragment that will show one step. This will result in cleaner, slide screen style guide.